# Asymptotic Distribution when variables are equivalent in probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Suppose that X and Y are two random variables, such that X-Y converges in probability to 0. 
My intuition tells me that if the asymptotic distribution of X*D is N(0,I), where D is just another random variable, then the distribution of Y*D is also N(0,I). 
Can somebody please explain if this is so, and why. I am interested in the mathematics behind this result.
Thanks very much.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky's_theorem

Comment: @mike - thanks for the link. I am a bit unsure how to proceed when X-Y converges to 0, yet one cannot say that X converges to Y in probability. An examples is when both X and Y depend on n.

Comment: What do you mean by "$X-Y$ converges in probability to 0"?  You don't have a sequence of random variables here.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson What I meant is that both X and Y are random variables which have the property that X-Y converges (in probability) to zero. For example, if Z is a co-variate matrix then X and Y can be given by X=Z'Z/n and Y =E[Z'Z]/n where one could assume that X-Y converges in probability to zero. My question then is whether I can conclude that if X*D converges in distribution to the standard normal, so does Y*D.

Comment: @Kristi This is bad notation -- $X$ and $Y$ have no visual dependence on $n$.  This makes it look as though $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, when you are really referring to sequences $X_n$ and $Y_n$ of random variables.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson You are right. Sorry for the confusion. I am relatively new to this.

Answer (score 0):

If $X_n-Y_n\xrightarrow{p}0$, then $P(X=Y)=1$. This implies the result.